# Excel - Scatter plot does not connect all data points

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

in Excel I have a chart with 5 scatterplots. The x-axis is always the same column. However, the last added scatterplot does not connect all data points (see figure). There are some blank cells in the dataset for the x-axes. In the figure I only displayed the last addded data set, because it didn't make any difference.

I hope someone can tell me how to fix this. Thanks in advance!

P.S. I wasn't able to upload a figure due to a lack of reputation points..

Comment: Post a normal link to your image. Other users with higher reputation will insert them for you

Comment: [Are you aware that Excel offers 3 different options on how to treat empty cells?](http://excelribbon.tips.net/T006289_Controlling_the_Plotting_of_Empty_Cells.html) `Show empty cells as 1) Gaps 2) Zero 3)Connect Data Points with Line.`

Answer (score 1):

After reading my own post, I gave it a try to see whether the blank cell were te problem. And surprisingly they were actually the problem. So I made sure there were no blank cells in the column of the x-axis and the corresponding y-values and problem solved!